# Vim opens another file instead of source (Syntastic?)

Tags: vimrc, plugin-syntastic

I have been using vim for a while now and have some plugins including syntastic.

I got a project with
`fileA.cpp`
`fileA.h`
`fileB.cpp`
`fileB.h`

While debugging, I run `vim fileA.cpp`, and it will open `fileB.h`. I do not understand why—I cannot open `fileA.cpp` at all. Any guess what might cause that?

`fg` indicates no such job.

I suppose it could be syntastic telling me an included file contains errors which have to be resolved before opening the desired file.

For example, `fileB.h` is included in `fileA.cpp`. Because `fileB.h` contains an error it will jump to that file.

Can anyone explain to me how to turn this off?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you reproduce this issue when you run `vim --clean` or `vim -u NONE`? If so, you might want to see [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Comment: thanks! When using `vim --clean` it isn't reproducing the error.

Comment: that’s a good indicator that something in your config or a plugin is the cause. Check out the debugging link I gave and see what other info you can get from that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is the option let:syntastic_auto_jump = 1 (2 or 3). All options lead to the auto jump to the first error, regardless of in which file it is. So it is impossible to use this option if you want to access the first error in the exact file. Good to know. Thanks for your supportive know-how.

Comment: no problem ! Please add an answer if you were able to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

The flag `let g:syntastic_auto_jump = 1` jumps to the first error as soon as `:w` is commanded, automatically.

In case a header contains an error it will jump there immediately.
Therefore, if the header is compromised that flag prohibits to enter the main file.

Commenting this flag out fixed the problem.